# How to insert hash into hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a simple hash defined somewhere in the main file

```
our %translations = (
    "phrase 1" => "translation 1",
    # ... and so on 
    );
```

In another file I want to add some more translations. That is, I want to do something like this:

```
push our %translations, (
    "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
    # ....
    "phrase M" => "something",
    );
```

Of course this code wouldn't work: `push` doesn't work with hashes. So my question is: what is a simple and elegant way to insert a hash of values into an existing hash?

I wouldn't want to resort to

```
$translations{"phrase N"} = "blah-blah";
# ....
$translations{"phrase M"} = "something";
```

since in Perl you're supposed to be able to do things without too much repetition in your code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign to a hash slice using the [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) functions.  As long as the hash isn't modified between the calls, `keys` will return the keys in the same order that `values` returns the values.

```
our %translations = (
  "phrase 1" => "translation 1",
);

{ # Braces just to restrict scope of %add
  my %add = (
    "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
    "phrase M" => "something",
  );
  @translations{keys %add} = values %add;
}

# Or, using your alternate syntax:
@translations{keys %$_} = values %$_ for {
  "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
  "phrase M" => "something",
};
```

Comment: This helps! I can even write it as `@translations{keys %$_} = values $%_ for {"phrase N" => "blah-blah", ...};`

Comment: That syntax didn't occur to me, but it is a clever shortcut.  The loop makes it probably a hair less efficient, but I doubt the difference is measurable.

Comment: well, it's a loop over a single element. More of a convenient way to assign the anonymous hash to the $_ variable.

Answer (score 18):

```
%translations = (%translations, %new_translations);
```

Comment: same principle as yi_H's answer, but showing that you can do it on existing hashes, not just while creating `%translations`

Answer (score 8):

You can assign to a hash slice:

```
@translations{@keys} = @values;
```

or using data from another hash:

```
@translations{keys %new} = values %new;
```

Comment: However since I'm adding many new keys, it will be really hard to keep track of the correspondence between the keys and their values (which translation corresponds to which phrase).

Comment: @user958624: you can use arrays for keys and values (see the update)

Answer (score 5):

```
%translations = (
    "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
    # ....
    "phrase M" => "something",
    %translations
    );
```

Comment: Does this copy the entire hash over? That is, suppose `%translations` contains several thousands entries already. Would you solution create a temp hash ("phrase N"=>..., "phrase M"=>..., <a copy of the original %translations>), and then assign this temp hash to the %translations? If so then there will be a significant overhead for using this method, if not then it seems simple enough!

Comment: @user958624: yes, it does. A new list value is constructed from these sublists and assigned to `%translations`

Answer (score 2):

`Hash::Merge` is another option: https://metacpan.org/module/Hash::Merge

also - don't worry too much about optimization in copying hashes - if it becomes a problem, look into it then. Just try and write good clear readable and maintainable code first of all. A hash of several thousand keys with string values is not large!

what you haven't specified in your question, is whether there will be any collision of keys (i.e. could there ever be two 'Phrase 1's read from the files...?

Comment: Hash::Merge is overkill unless you have a nested data structure or need special treatment of duplicate keys.

Comment: i agree, it is in this case, but useful to know the existance of, so thought i'd just mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I know, it's already said. But I want highlight an aspect:

Following overwrites existing values in you hash:

```pl
%translations = (
    %translations,
    "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
    "phrase M" => "something"
    );
```

Following does not:

```pl
%translations = ( 
    "phrase N" => "blah-blah",
    "phrase M" => "something",
    %translations
    );
```

---

Example 1

```pl
my %translations = ( a => 'first', b => 'second');
%translations = (%translations, a => 'at first', c => 'third');
```

Now you have:

```txt
"a" => "at first"  # its overwritten by the new value
"b" => "second"
"c" => "third"
```

---

Example 2

```pl
my %translations = ( a => 'first', b => 'second');
%translations = (a => 'at first', c => 'third', %translations);
```

Now you have:

```txt
"a" => "first"  # the old value is not overwritten
"b" => "second"
"c" => "third"
```